# Can anyone who knows my webapplication folder structure access my scripts via Ajax

Tags: ajax, security, filesystems

I Have Made a **WebApplication** which Uses **ajax** as its **core** for all functionality

My doubt is site user can view the js files as well as ajax calls made in **browser(view source option)**

Users will be able to **see the script** i'm hitting using the above method.

if users can write an ajax call which hits the same script from there local machine or anywhere , this will lead to a **security issue**

I wanted to make my scripts accessible only to my code , how to **secure** it .

Answer (score 1):

you can't. your code runs on client's browser so you never know what happens there. your js code is NOT secure. it can be altered and use in any way. your server-side code must be secure instead

you can't limit what your js does but your server has to give some kind of grants. for example your server can sign the ticket to grant access for next 10 seconds to some specific api and later check if the ticket was passed with the request. but still: you have no control over how that ticket will be used by the frontend

Comment: is there some possibility like restricting folder access to only my domain or programs in my domain may be using .htaccess???

Comment: whatever you do, you can't distinguish if call is made by your script or if it's manually created/copied request. user can create request that looks like from your domain. unless you use some kind of signing (then user can only copy requests)